# java timer with swing component

Tags: java, swing, reference, timer

I need to make a timer that pass a reference to the component

```
    Timer timertest = new Timer(12000, new Timer());
.............
{
    JButton button = new JButton("test");
    //How can I pass button reference in the Timer()?
    //timertest.start(button);
    timertest.start();
}
.............
class Timer implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    {
        System.out.println("button: "+button.getText());
        timertest.stop();
    }
}
```

How can I pass button reference in the Timer()?

Comment: You solve this just as you would pass any reference in Java be it Swing or non-GUI. For e.g., why not make the button a class field, and pass the reference to it into the Timer object via a constructor or setter method parameter?

Comment: Also you'll want to rename your "Timer" class since there already is a Timer class in core Java (actually two of them) and naming your class the same thing is quite confusing.

Comment: Just to clarify: your variable timertest is an instance of your own Timer class and not java.util.Timer?

Comment: @steffinchen: timertest is a javax.swing.Timer variable.

Comment: why? what exactly do you want to achieve?

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest you write your own subclass of Timer (`class MyTimer extends Timer`) and then you can pass a reference to the button either in the constructor or your own method.

For example:

```
class MyTimer extends Timer{
  public void start(JButton button){
     // use the button reference
    super.start(); 
}
```

Comment: Down-voted. There's absolutely no reason to do this, and this is a bad idea since no behaviors of Timer are overridden. Even more important is that he has already created a class for the Timer's ActionListener and that is all that is needed to hold a reference to the JButton.

Comment: Now that I have looked at the question again for a couple of minutes, I realized that he was talking about passing the reference to his own class. I tought he was talking about the java.util.Timer... So, yes, I agree, my suggestion then is a bad idea